# No scrollbars in Spotify Preview API

Tags: spotify

I'm currently migrating my spotify app to the new preview api. One of many issues that I'm experiencing is no scrolling is possible. When content is too long for the viewport no scrollbars appear.

Anybody with the same issue and possible solution? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably a CSS rule preventing scrollbars from appearing. After requesting the CSS that are part of the Spotify Views, make sure you set the `overflow` property of the `html` element to `auto`:

`html { overflow: auto; }`

Comment: The strange thing is `overflow: hidden` coming from the spotify base.css. I specified `overflow: auto` in my own css but it is not overwriting the hidden value ...also tried to add !important...anyway your point was right :)!thx

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

is the solution!